# CSS accordion - Content of the checkbox are going over the footer

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to update BESIX Group Structure with an accordion (made with css only) with checkboxes.
My issue is: I don't find the reason when I click on a tab, the content goes over the footer and the rest of the content..

Could you help me?

Link: https://www.besix.com/en/about/2019-group-structure

Thanks,
Kind regards,

I tried a lot of differents codes on Codepen, like this one: https://codepen.io/vinsongrant/pen/qbGKed -> Same issue

or this one https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/wvlgs, it's not working at all on our Sitecore environment.

```
 .accordion {

    position:relative;
    font-family:Oxygen, sans-serif;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
    }
    .accordion ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    .accordion li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    .accordion [type=radio], .accordion [type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
    }
    .accordion label {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:#0099da;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }
    .accordion ul li label:hover, .accordion [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .accordion [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    background:#21409a;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
    }
    .accordion .contentaccordion {
    padding:0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #fff; /* Make the border match the background so it fades in nicely */
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    max-height:2000px;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
z-index:99;
    }
```

Comment: On your website, there is a fixed height set on your div, 362px. that is causing the issue

Comment: Please show us your html in a [mcve] in the question itself - see [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the accordion. There is an inline style, hardcoded or added by JavaScript.
You need to remove it in order to push the content instead to go over it.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 matchHeight" style="height: 362px">
```